# Is it possible to specify the display format for a dijit.form.DateTextBox

Tags: date, dojo

Is it possible to specify the display format for a dijit.form.DateTextBox?

I know that dijit.form.DateTextBox gets its date format from the user's locale by default and I know I can swtich the locale to anything I want, but I need to just specify the date format and not change anything else. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```javascript
var occursOnField = new dijit.form.DateTextBox({
    constraints: { datePattern : 'yyyy-MM-dd' }
    , promptMessage: "yyyy-MM-dd"
    , invalidMessage: "Invalid date format. Use yyyy-MM-dd"
})
```

Update Jan 29, 2012:

Chrome and Dojo 1.6.1 compatibility bug.

If the day of month is being padded with too many 0s, use one less `d` in the date pattern to work around the bug. For example, on Google Chrome 16 and Dojo 1.6.1 : `datePattern : 'yyyy-MM-dd'` will give 2010-01-001 and `datePattern : 'yyyy-MM-d'` will give 2010-01-1.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple thing:

```
    <input type="text"  name="Date"  id="myDate" promptMessage="Please Enter Date" value="" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" constraints="{datePattern:'dd-MMM-yyyy', strict:true}"  />
```

Comment: Please add some description for your "simple thing" to improve your answer.